# Elementary question regarding sentential logic

Tags: logic

Sorry if this question is too elementary than usual for this site, but I'm trying to analyze the logical form of the following statement:

3 is a common divisor of 6, 9, and 15.

I'm not sure how to go about constructing its logical form. I'm assuming I only have to look at its meaning and leaving the superfluous details out. But when I tried constructing it, it didn't feel or sound right, so I tried looking up a solution.

Let T = 3 is a common divisor, S = 3 is a common divisor of 6, N = 3 is a common divisor of 9, F = 3 is a common divisor of 15

This is what I got: [(T $\wedge$ S) $\wedge$ (T $\wedge$ N) $\wedge$ (T $\wedge$ F)]

I'm assuming one of my mistakes was introducing an auxiliary element (i.e T) that shouldn't have been there. This is an exercise in Velleman's *How To Prove it*, specifically chapter 1, number 2(c). I tried looking up a solution since there wasn't one in the appendix, and I found [this](http://diovo.com/2012/10/how-to-prove-it-exercise-1-1-2/). As you can see, my solution seems to be way off.

**QUESTION:**
Is this correct? And if so, what does the solution mean? (i.e what do the terms represent? what does "6 mod 3 = 0" mean?) I'm still in the beginning of the book so I haven't seen/been introduced to some of these terms, and it came as quite a surprise.

Also, you'll have to forgive my LaTeX noobiness. To be fair, I never even heard of it until I came across this site, so I'm still learning. Feel free to edit my question. Any help would be appreciated (regarding the problem, not LaTeX) thank you! =)

Comment: The format "$a$ is a common divisor of $b$" is not right. By a common divisor is meant a number which divides *two or more* other numbers, at least as the term "common divisor" is used.

Comment: And the statement "3 is a common divisor" is just complete nonsense.

Comment: Sorry, but I was never the best math student. I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Well, at this stage it is rather a linguistic problem. "My grandfather is a common ancestor of my uncle, my cousin and me" makes sense. "My grandfather is a common ancestor of my uncle and also a common ancestor of my cousin and also a common ancestor of me" makes no sense.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem, I think, is not understanding exactly what is meant by the statement that $3$ is a common divisor of $6,9$, and $15$. This simply means that $3$ is a divisor of $6$, $3$ is a divisor of $9$, and $3$ is a divisor of $15$. And when you paraphrase it that way, its structure becomes very evident: it’s just $S\land N\land F$, where $S,N$, and $F$ are the statements ‘$3$ is a divisor of $6$’, ‘$3$ is a divisor of $9$’, and ‘$3$ is a divisor of $15$’, respectively.

You could go a little further and notice that these three statements themselves all have the same basic structure. If $T(n)$ is the ‘open’ statement ‘$3$ is a divisor of $n$’, then your original sentence has the logical form $T(6)\land T(9)\land T(15)$.

Comment: This is a very intuitive explanation for me. thanks for clearing up the confusion. And you are probably right.. I think I ended up being concerned about the structure and disregarded the meaning of what I was writing, so I wrote something nonsensical like "T = 3 is a common divisor".

Comment: @randommathsstudent: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$a \mod b = c$ means exist $p\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a = p*b +c$. So $6 \mod 3 =0$ exactly means $3$ is a divisor of $6$.

For your answer, your $T$ as no meaning "3 is a common divisor" of what?
But $S,N,F$ or ok. Remark that $S\equiv 6 \mod 3 =0$, $N\equiv 9 \mod 3 =0$ and $F\equiv 15 \mod 3 =0$.

So the answer $S\wedge N \wedge F$ is correct.